# How to find the default connection method used in SAML 2.0

Tags: saml-2.0

Kindly let us know, what are all the connection method available in SAML2.0 and which one used by default. Also, please let us know, where we can find that information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about SAML from a browser it's just https.

It's just POSTS and GETS.

The specification is on [OASIS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0.pdf).

Comment: Actually, we are using the below library to connect SAML.
[https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml]

We just followed the demo1 folder given by them.
Could you please let us know which connection method they were used to connect with SAML [https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/tree/master/demo1]